# How to return a boolean tensor depending on condition?

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-lightning

Let the cartesian product between a set of `query_idx` and another set of `doc_idx` as shown below:

```py
torch.cartesian_prod(preds["query_idx"], preds["doc_idx"])
# tensor([
#     [0, 9], [0, 5], [0, 7], [1, 9], [1, 5], [1, 7], [2, 9], [2, 5], [2, 7]
# ])
```

Also consider the relevance map, stating which documents are relevant in relation to a given query:

```py
relevance_map = {
    0: [5,9], # the docs 5 and 9 are relevant results concerning the query 0.
    1: [9],
    2: [5,7]
}
```

Then, how to generate a new tensor classifying each pair of the cartesian product as `TRUE` (relevant) or `False` (non-relevant) according to the relevance map?

```py
torch.tensor([
    True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True
])
```

Comment: maybe it's me but I don't really understand how to determine what's ``True`` and whats ``False``

Comment: It is `TRUE` when the cartesian pair [x, y] exists in the `relevance_map`: ```y is in relevance_map[x]```.